# Pika python wait for RabbitMQ Publisher if queue reach limit

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have a scenario , a python script that will publish let's say 150k message with each message size 10kb at max. Then i will set the queue limit to maximum 5000 message. Then the publisher will publish message into queue until it reach the limit 5000 message. Then the consumer will try to consume the message.

What i want to ask is, can publisher wait for publishing message if the queue is full? without discarding the message. Will check again if the queue available, then publisher will publish the data.

Comment: I imagine that if the queue is full, then pika would raise an exception. Could you try setting the max queue size to something really small and seeing what happens?

Comment: I already try it, set the x-max-length to 10. Use basic_publish, but always return true even queue full.

Comment: When you do so, do all messages seem to be queued or do some fail silently? It could be that `basic_publish` blocks until it is able to publish.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a recent RabbitMQ version (like `3.7.5`), you can set the [`overflow` behavior](https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html#overflow-behaviour) to `reject-publish`. Then, in your code, use the `channel_instance.confirm_delivery()` method to enable publisher confirms. Finally, when the queue limit is reached, a `basic.nack` message will be sent back to your code and will raise a `NackError` exception that you can catch.

Comment: That solution stated that the message will be discarded when queue is full, but i dont want to discarded the message. I have to make sure all message get inserted into the queue.

Comment: My answer is correct. Please re-read that document **carefully**.  You must combine `reject-publish` with publisher confirms and you will get negative acknowledgements. This is why I mentioned the `confirm_delivery` method call. Your application will then be responsible for catching the `NackError` and re-trying the publish after a period of time that you determine.